# Comparing Two Text Files, Removing the duplicate lines, and Writing results to a new text file

Tags: python, compare, lines

I have two text files (that are not equal in number of lines/size). I would like to compare each line of the shorter text file with every line of the longer text file. As it compares, if there are any duplicate strings, I would like to have those removed. Lastly, I would like write the result to a new text file and print the contents.

Is there a simply script that can do this for me?

Any help would be much appreciated.

The text files are not very large. One has about 10 lines and the other has about 5. The code I have tried (that failed miserably) is below:

```
for line in file2:
line1 = line
for line in file1:
    requested3 = file('request2.txt','a')
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(line1,line):
        line2 = line.replace(line,"")
        requested3.write(line2)
    if not fnmatch.fnmatch(line1,line):
        requested3.write(line+'\n')


    requested3.close()
```

Comment: Just to clarify - your want to output the strings from the short text file, subtracting any strings from the short text file that are in the long text file? Also, how large are each of these files, and what code have you written thus far?

Answer (score 4):

```
with open(longfilename) as longfile, open(shortfilename) as shortfile, open(newfilename, 'w') as newfile:
    newfile.writelines(line for line in shortfile if line not in set(longfile))
```

It's as simple as that. This will copy lines from `shortfile` to `newfile`, without having to keep them all in memory, if they also exist in `longfile`.

If you're on Python 2.6 or older, you would need to nest the with statements:

```
with open(longfilename) as longfile: 
    with open(shortfilename) as shortfile:
        with open(newfilename, 'w') as newfile:
```

If you're on Python 2.5, you need to either:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

at the **very top** of your file, or just use

```
longfile = open(longfilename)
```

etc. and close each file yourself.

If you need to manipulate the lines, an explicit `for` loop is fine, the important part is `set()`. Looking up an item in a set is fast, looking up a line in a long list is slow.

```
longlines = set(line.strip_or_whatever() for line in longfile)
for line in shortfile:
    if line not in longlines:
        newfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Do I need to import a library? My code is not recognizing the with statement?

Comment: Update your post to mention which version of python you are using. When your run python from the command line, it will say the version (ex: Python 2.7.1, Python 2.6, etc)

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify Python 2.5 situation.

Comment: My version is 2.6.4. Still doesn't know what the with statement is.

Comment: You're either wrong about the version or you didn't separately nest the with statements as I indicated you need to with Python 2.6. See http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement. `with` and `as` are reserved words and it's a standard language feature in 2.6, 2.5 you need the `future` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the files are both plain text, each string is on a new line delimited with \n newline characters:

```
small_file = open('file1.txt','r')
long_file = open('file2.txt','r')
output_file = open('output_file.txt','w')

try:
    small_lines = small_file.readlines()
    long_lines = long_file.readlines()
    small_lines_cleaned = [line.rstrip().lower() for line in small_lines]
    long_file_lines = long_file.readlines()
    long_lines_cleaned = [line.rstrip().lower() for line in long_lines]

    for line in small_lines_cleaned:
        if line not in long_lines_cleaned:
            output_file.writelines(line + '\n')

finally:
    small_file.close()
    long_file.close()
    output_file.close()
```

Explanation:

1. Since you can't get 'with' statements working, we open the files first using regular open functions, then use a try...finally clause to close them at the end of the program.
2. We take the small file and the long file and first remove any trailing '\n' (newline) characters with .rstrip(), then make all the characters lower-case with .lower(). If you have two sentences identical in every aspect except one has upper case letters and the other doesn't, they wont' match. Forcing them lower case avoids that; if you prefer a case-sensitive compare, remove the .lower() method.
3. We go line by line in small_lines_cleaned (for line in...) and see if it is in the larger file.
4. Output each line if it is not in the longer file; we add the '\n' newline character so that each line will appear on a new line, insteadOfOneGiantLongSetOfStrings

Comment: You're assuming it's OK to modify the lines a lot... I can see `rstrip()` but `lower()` can change meaning. Looking through a long list is also slow; this is exactly what `set()` is for.

Comment: Edited the description to more explicitly state the purpose of .lower() (so it can be removed if unwanted). Also there only 10 lines in the long file making speed issues trivial - I tried to keep it very simple and read-able so it could be understood.

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying to do this for days. It's perfect.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you  'accept' it by clicking Check mark next to the answer ^^

Comment: NameError: name 'long_lines' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html), it makes it easy to do comparisons/diffs. There is a nice tutorial for it [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/difflib/). If you just wanted the lines that were unique to the shorter file:

```
from difflib import ndiff

short = open('short.txt').readlines()
long = open('long.txt').readlines()

with open('unique.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(x[2:] for x in ndiff(short, long) if x.startswith('-')))
```

Comment: That's not the kind of comparison the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: difflib does not support the kind of comparison the OP wants to do? In what way? It's just text.

Comment: @hughdbrown, difflib applies to case where one file is a modified version of the other and you want to find the changes. I don't think the OP is doing that.

Comment: @Winston the OP seems to want the lines in the short text that are not in the long, which is pretty easy to do with difflib: `[x[2:] for x in difflib.ndiff(short, long) if x.startswith('-')]`

Comment: But does he care about the order of the second file? I assumed not and so do all the other answers. But its hard to say from the question.

Comment: A caveat of this approach is that the lines in common must follow the same ordering between the files. If appropriate to the situation it's a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands checks each line against the line in the other file. But that's not what you want. For each line in the first file, you need to check whether any line in the other file matches and then print it out if there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

The following code reads file two and checks it against file one.Anything that's **in file one** but **not in file two** will get printed and also written to a new text file.

If you wanted to do the opposite, you'd just get rid of the "not" from if statement below. So it'd print anything that's **in file one** and **in file two**.

It works by putting the contents of the shorter file (file two) in a variable and then reading the longer file (file one) line by line. Each line is checked against the variable and then the line is either written or not written to the text file according to it's presence in the variable.

(Remember to remove the stars surrounding the not statement if you wish to use it, or removing the not statement all together if you want it to print the matching words.)

```
fileOne = open("LONG FILE.ext","r")
fileTwo = open("SHORT FILE.ext","r")
fileThree = open("Results.txt","a+")

contents = fileTwo.read()

numLines = sum(1 for line in fileOne)
for i in range (numLines):
    if **not** fileOne.readline(i) in contents:
        print (fileOne.readline(i))
        fileThree.write (fileOne.readline(i))
        
fileOne.close()
fileTwo.close()
fileThree.close()
```